# Creating iOS framework: how to prevent insight into source code while debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I've just developed my own (universal) framework with Xcode. When I import it into a test project (which definitely needs the classes of my framework), all runs well - both with the simulator as well as a real device (iPhone).

I've built a debug and a release version.

Under "edit schemes", I've also disabled "view debugging" within the release version.

However, when I set a break point into my source code of my test project (which - as mentioned - fetches some info from the release version of my framework), I can still step into the classes (.m files) without any problems.

As I want to deliver this framework to paying customers, I want to prevent anybody from seeing my source code while debugging. Experimenting with several flags in "build settings" had no effect ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the Run Script which is used to generate the Framework.

Comment: I got the script and the "cookbook" from
https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c

The script is too long to paste it - but you can find it in the URL above

Answer (score 14):

nobody could help me, so I rookie had to help myself :-)

The solution could no bet easier:
just goto Targets -> Build Settings and then make a search for "Generate Debug Symbols" - arrived there, simply change form YES to NO

... and that's it!

Happy Frameworking :-)

Comment: Yes, this works. But by setting this config as NO, dsyms file will not be generated and we will not be able to symbolicate crashes which client faces. How have you solved this? Are you able to symbolicate crashes in your framework?